# Software Updater not updating 14.04

Tags: update-manager

I have tried all solution. installed ppa manager, run the sudo apt-get update command but still its not working. It shows the pop-up for update and when i click ok, it says installation of untrusted files. And if i press ok it gets closed. what to do. i m using asus x 550cc

Comment: What are you installing that isnt from the Universe Repos?

Comment: No i m installing nothing. I got some updates from software updater. So i want to install those updates.

Answer (score -1):

Try performing the full update via a terminal, like this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

(update only syncronizes the package lists, it doesn't actually perform any installations)

If it is not able to process any/some of the downloads or installations, it should provide a more detailed description of what's wrong.

Comment: 'W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/sgringwe/rdio/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/sgringwe/rdio/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.'

Comment: Above error i got from sudo apt-get update.

Answer (score -1):

unfortunately you can't fetch  ppa.launchpad.net/sgringwe/rdio/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/…
because the repository doesn't exist for trusty.
As I could see, the newest Version of that repo is for Raring. So you can try and change the repo to raring and see if the packages of that version are good to go in trusty or deactivate/delete the repos.